# How to prevent custom shape from pushing out of the LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, message, shapes

I have a Custom View that extends RelativeLayout with overridden onDraw() method so that it looks like a message bubble. This View is in the LinearLayout. When I try to fill this custom View with content, part of its shape is pushed out of the LinearLayout. How to prevent this behaviour?How to prevent this behaviour?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="2:46pm"
        android:textSize="@dimen/splash_4_user_name_text_size" />

    <com.mypackage.RightBasedMessage
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/splash_3_comment_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/splash_3_comment_end_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/chat_message_field_beginning_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/splash_3_comment_padding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi :)"
            android:textColor="@color/white_text_color" />

    </com.mypackage.RightBasedMessage>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Custom View:

```
public class RightBasedMessage extends RelativeLayout {

private Paint paint;
private Path path;
private Point pointleftTop;
private Point pointRightTop;
private Point pointRightBottom;
private Point pointLeftBottom;
private float corner;
private Context context;
private int color = R.color.chat_my_message_field_color;

public RightBasedMessage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    corner = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.message_container_corner);
    paint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public void setMessageBackground(int color){
    this.color = color;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    pointRightTop = new Point(width-(int)corner, (int)corner/2);
    pointRightBottom = new Point(width-(int)corner, height);
    pointLeftBottom = new Point(0, height);
    pointleftTop = new Point(0, 0);
    path.reset();

    path.moveTo(corner, 0);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    path.quadTo(pointRightTop.x, pointRightTop.y, width-corner, corner+corner/2);
    path.lineTo(width-corner, height-corner);
    path.quadTo(pointRightBottom.x, pointRightBottom.y, width - corner*2, height);
    path.lineTo(corner, height);
    path.quadTo(pointLeftBottom.x, pointLeftBottom.y, 0, height-corner);
    path.lineTo(0, corner);
    path.quadTo(pointleftTop.x, pointleftTop.y, corner, 0);

    paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    path.close();
}
```

}

Comment: This happens because of View with weight="1". But without it I can`t force time textView to be near the message.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
>
```